# Make a list of people who reacted a specific message

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to make a list of people who reacted to a **specific message** in discord ?

**ID du message :** '315274607072378891'

**Channel :** '846414975156092979'

**Reaction :** ✅

The code will be executed here:

```
bot.on("ready", async () => {
}
```

Result :

```
Reaction_users: [
id_user1,
id_user2,
...]
```

Thank you in advance for the help given.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to fetch the message `channel.fetchMessage();`.
The Channel can be fetched using `client.channels.cache.get('id')`.

So in total you can do something like

```
bot.on("ready", async () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('846414975156092979');
    const message = channel.fetch('315274607072378891');
    const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.id);
    console.log(userReactions)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch message first then you need to get reactions from message

Solution:

```js
bot.on("ready", async () => {
   let channel = bot.channels.cache.get('846414975156092979');
   let message = channel.fetch('315274607072378891');
   let reactions = messsage.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.id);
}
```

Comment: He needs a list of user id not user

Comment: Would it not be better to use `.map()` rather than `.filter()`?

Comment: It will be same in this case I think so

Comment: @HellCatVN Thank you very much for your help, it's very nice.
The problem is not solved. Here is the table :


users: ReactionUserManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    reaction: [Circular *2]
  },

 
 
let reactions = message.reactions.cache.get(emoji_giveaway).users.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.id);
console.log(reactions)


Result : Collection(0) [Map] {}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help, it's very nice.
The problem is not solved. Here is the table:

```
users: ReactionUserManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    reaction: [Circular *2]
},
```

```
let reactions = message.reactions.cache.get(EMOJI).users.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.id);

console.log(reactions)
```

Result : Collection(0) [Map] {}

Comment: the code given is not match solution I gave you above